# Extremely slow internet over ethernet cable and no WiFi at all on HPG5000

Tags: 12.04, networking

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on an old HP G5000

There is no WiFi and the  internet connection is extremely slow over the ethernet cable, seems no more that few Kb/s, e.g. the browser is able to download the page title, but nothing else. The ethernet cable works perfectly with other laptops and it worked perfectly with the same laptop when it had Windows just 1 hour prior to installing Ubuntu. I am new to Linux. Executed a few lines of code in the Terminal that were used in other similar topics, but I have very limited understanding on what it all means.

```
inese@inese-HP:~$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:38:2f:04:8d  
          inet addr:192.168.2.125  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 
          inet6 addr: fe80::21b:38ff:fe2f:48d/64 Scope:Link 
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
          RX packets:122 errors:68 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:186 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:33749 (33.7 KB)  TX bytes:26731 (26.7 KB) 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1 
          RX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3404 (3.4 KB)  TX bytes:3404 (3.4 KB) 

inese@inese-HP:~$ netstat -nr 
Kernel IP routing table 
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface 
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0 
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0 
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0 

inese@inese-HP:~$ ping -c 4 google.com 
PING google.com (195.122.16.29) 56(84) bytes of data. 
64 bytes from cache.google.com (195.122.16.29): icmp_req=1 ttl=60 time=23.4 ms 
64 bytes from cache.google.com (195.122.16.29): icmp_req=2 ttl=60 time=23.5 ms 
64 bytes from cache.google.com (195.122.16.29): icmp_req=3 ttl=60 time=22.0 ms 
64 bytes from cache.google.com (195.122.16.29): icmp_req=4 ttl=60 time=23.6 ms

--- google.com ping statistics --- 
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms 
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.043/23.155/23.650/0.656 ms 

inese@inese-HP:~$ sudo lshw -c network 
  *-network               
       description: Network controller 
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN 
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation 
       physical id: 0 
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0 
       version: 01 
       width: 32 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list 
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0 
       resources: irq:18 memory:40400000-40403fff 
  *-network 
       description: Ethernet interface 
       product: RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ 
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
       physical id: 8 
       bus info: pci@0000:08:08.0 
       logical name: eth0 
       version: 10 
       serial: 00:1b:38:2f:04:8d 
       size: 100Mbit/s 
       capacity: 100Mbit/s 
       width: 32 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation 
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=8139too driverversion=0.9.28 duplex=full ip=192.168.2.125 latency=32 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s 
       resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0100000-d01000ff 
inese@inese-HP:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -ia2 net 
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:30a5] 
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801 
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01) 
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4311 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [103c:1364] 
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge 
    Kernel modules: ssb 
08:08.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ [10ec:8139] (rev 10) 
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:30a5] 
    Kernel driver in use: 8139too
```

Thank you!
Atis

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I can't anything out of the ordinary, could you please post the result of `wget www.askubuntu.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless requires firmware. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

After a reboot, your wireless should be working.